# silex.phar redirecting me

Tags: php, symfony1, silex

I am using a local domain, mysite.dev, and when I access a url that would be served by silex it redirects me to www.mysite.dev

I was able to single out the line causing the problem in my code:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/silex.phar';
```

anyone know any remedies for this ?

Comment: that is just the archive file used to run silex. Is there something in your code that is redirecting to www.mysite.dev? e..g $app->redirect('//www.mysite.dev');

Comment: gunnx: i put a die statement before the require and it was hit, so i moved the statement after the require and it doesn't get it because it redirects

Comment: that does sound very odd, would it be possible for you to upgrade to the latest silex that no longer uses the .phar

Answer (score 0):

The [PHP configuration](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/phar.html#php-configuration) section advices might help fixing your problem.

I suggest you nevertheless installing Silex via Composer as recommended by the documentation:

> Using the Silex phar file is deprecated. You should use Composer instead to install Silex and its dependencies or download one of the archives.